# Whitespaces in URL causing wget to fail

Tags: bash, wget

I have a URL like so:
`http://localhost:8999/createAudio?method=createAudio&sessionId=1234&text=${line}&voice=Paul&encoder=MP3";`
Where `${line}` is "This is such a nice day."
I am using `wget` to capture the output of the above http request like so:
`cURL="http://localhost:8999/createAudio?method=createAudio&sessionId=1234&text=${line}&voice=Sangeeta&encoder=MP3";

wget -O test.html ${cURL}`

My problem is that the http request cuts at the first instance of a white space. So the http request that would be issued would go like:
`http://localhost:8999/createAudio?method=createAudio&sessionId=1234&text=This`

How do I ensure that the entire `${line}` gets used in the http request?

Comment: Spaces must be encoded in URLs. Replace with `%20`.

Comment: Show the full command line. Start by placing the URL in double quotes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One answer would be to simply URL-encode your spaces as `%20`, getting rid of any literal spaces.

However, `wget` will do this for you. Your problem here is that you've correctly quoted when you're initializing the `cURL` variable, but not when you're actually *using* it in the curl command line. You need to quote there also, or else bash will interpret any spaces in that variable as argument separators:

```
wget -O test.html "$cURL"
```